# Arch - Solve: Cannot Set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, arch-linux, locale, settings

I would like to change my locale in a VM running Arch.

I'm following the documentation for Arch at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale and did this:

1. Uncommented the language I want to try **yi_US.UTF-8** on `/etc/locale.gen` and commented all other languages.
2. Ran the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

locale-gen
localectl set-locale LANG=yi_US.UTF-8
unset LANG
source /etc/profile.d/locale.sh
```

When I run `locale` after the script I'm getting:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Camnot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8”
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIF ICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

As I understand that the 3 errors above are because the **en_US.UTF-8** locale is not available anymore since I commented it out in `/etc/locale.gen`.

My output of `localectl`:

```
System Locale: LANG=yi_US.UTF-8
```

And in `/etc/locale.conf` I have:

```
LANG=yi_US.UTF-8
```

It seems that when I run `unset LANG` and `source /etc/profile.d/locale.sh` in the script the changes only affect the running script, so the changes aren't permanent.

How can I make the `LC_*` use the new locale **yi_US.UTF-8** in parent shell and all system permanently through the script?

I have read that I should run: `export LC_ALL=yi_US.UTF-8`, but this doesn't seem correct, this would only work for current terminal session.

Do I have to add `LC_ALL=yi_US.UTF-8` or the list of `LC_*` to `/etc/locale.conf` to solve the problem?